# Error 404 en lugar de imagen (que sí está en el servidor)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Tengo una carpeta de imágenes en un servidor con una ruta absoluta

```
https://www.elsitio.com/imagenes/imagen.jpg
```

Pero al abrir esa url en un explorador sale el error 404 en lugar de mostrar la imagen. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Es posible que el archivo `imagen.php` no esté realmente en esa ruta que en la que crees que está. ¿La carpeta `imagenes` está en `public_html` o su equivalente?

Comment: Definitivamente no se encuentra el archivo en la ruta, sería buena idea agregaras una imagen de donde se encuentra "public_html"

Answer (score 0):

Si tu servidor es linux,unix prueba que la ruta este escrita como en el servidor prueba las minúsculas y mayúscula.

Verifica el DocumetRoot de la configuración de Apache y revisa que coincida con la ruta en el servidor y la url.

Verifica que no exista un alias o un location a para carpeta imágenes en la configuración de apache.